# Can i upload a video on youtube and restrict it to be viewed on my website only?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

Can I upload a video on Youtube and restrict it to be viewed on my website only? I don't want it to be viewed directly on Youtube.

Comment: as i recall , you can't if you are uploading it to youtube

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can.

Check out Restrict Embedding on youtube.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6301625?hl=en

According to this document, you can block other website trying to embed your video.

"Allow on certain domains (in apps based on ID) – Block embedding on all sites or apps except for those URLs or app package names you enter in the text box."

Comment: Thank you for the reference

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, when you upload to the youtube platform there's an option to select for this reason actually. Just make sure your video is not set to public. Set it to private that way only the URL and those who have access to it can view the video. Next you just need to take that URL and put in your website. That way it stays private on youtube but when people visit your website they'll see it through said link.

Comment: Be aware though that other people can still embed the video on their own site, to my knowledge you can't restrict embeds on a per-url basis.

Comment: that's fair but if you embed a media player on the site that used a specific mp4 file to access and play, that could work right? But then you wouldn't need YT because there would be a localized file playing

Comment: can someone download the video from the website with apps like youtube downloaded or 4k video downloader?

Comment: I suppose so if they the video on the site when clicked brings them to the youtube URL, but I have never actually tested that out. You could test that idea on your own and comment back what you find out for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can only if u are a youtube partner (1000 sub and 4000 watches hours last year)

So my advice is to go for Vimeo: 7 dollars / month (payed annually) is the vimeo plus price, containing domain restriction. (if u are a student you can get 50% off, search for it)